# How to completely disable laptop touchpads?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, touchpad

I own a HP G70-460US. I recently upgraded to Windows 8 with this laptop, and the Synaptics touchpad driver is giving me a lot of BSOD. However, if I uninstall the driver, the touchpad will be permanently enabled, with tapping enabled, no palm protection, and the surface becomes extremely sensitive. The touchpad enabling button on the laptop will not work. This makes typing extremely difficult. I don't use touchpad at all and this had become quite an annoyance.

The closest solution that I found is TouchFreeze. However it still allows the pointer to move around, and of course, only temporarily disable clicks for a short time. It also requires keypress for it to block touchpad clicks.

Comment: Doesn’t your laptop have a *disable-touchpad* hotkey, something like `Fn+F7`?

Comment: And you can edit your question to provide more information instead of posting updates as answers.

Comment: Check your system's BIOS setup menu - I've seen a touchpad disable option in a couple systems.

Comment: If you want to keep track of this question, register your account

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any 3rd party software. Simply go into the Device Manager (I'm presuming you're using Windows), and find the touchpad in the list. If you right-click -> disable, Windows will completely disable that device.